# cURL PHP - Recuperando html da página

Tags: php, html, ajax, html5, libcurl

Olá,

Estou treinando esse cURL. Vocês podem me dizer porque o seguinte trecho não funciona?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $cURL = curl_init('http://fiesselecaoaluno.mec.gov.br/consulta/curso');
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $dados = array(
        'opcaoProcurar' => 'I',
        'noIes' => '10',
    );
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dados);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://fiesselecaoaluno.mec.gov.br/consulta/curso');
    $resultado = curl_exec($cURL);
    curl_close($cURL);
    echo $resultado;
    ?>
</body>
```

Eu queria pegar o html com o cURL, mas só dps dele ter preenchido o formulário corretamente. Alguma dica?

Tem alguma coisa a ver com o formulário da página, ou é por ser ajax e o curl não funciona pra isso ?

Comment: Em que ambiente você esta usando este script?

Comment: Como está o HTML do formulário?

Comment: Acabei de analisar o formulário e pelo que vi, ele é Ajax e não aceitaria a logica do script que você fez.

Comment: Era só eu entrar na url pra onde encaminha o post, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O serviço a que estás a fazer o `post` está errado, deve ser `http://fiesselecaoaluno.mec.gov.br/consulta/consulta`:

```
$cURL = curl_init('http://fiesselecaoaluno.mec.gov.br/consulta/consulta');
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$dados = array(
    'opcaoProcurar' => 'I',
    'noIes' => '10',
);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dados);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://fiesselecaoaluno.mec.gov.br/consulta/curso');
$resultado = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
echo $resultado;
```

Neste caso, consegues ver a que serviço se vai fazer `post` pela action do formulário

Comment: Era isso msm, resolvido.

Comment: só uma dúvida, ele escreve as tabela na página, tem como eu recuperar os dados do ajax sem precisar copiar todo o html da página ?

Comment: @MauricioMaletta agora não estou no computador, mas quais dados? Tu não querias o html?

Comment: não, achei umas funções legais: loadHTML() e getElementsByTagName(). Acho que dá pra fazer com elas, eu quero pegar os dados das tabelas e colocar em array, pra manter a estrutura da tabela, mas sem o código html.

Comment: @MauricioMaletta, mas tu já tens o html dentro de $resultado, mas como fazes o echo para o browser (navegador) ele randeriza isso... Podes comprovar isto se fizeres `echo htmlentities($resultado);` no fim

Comment: eu só queria limpar o html, parece q terei q usar expressões regulares

Comment: @MauricioMaletta podes usar http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/